# How to insert long time in milliseconds to Date in Oracle using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a long type which stores the milliseconds since epoch and I want to insert that into oracle Date using jdbc prepared statements. I tried the following -

```
String query =  "insert into tempp values(? , ?)";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

String longString1 = "1521142078000";
String longString2 = "1521566664738";

long longType1 = new Long(longString1).longValue();
long longType2 = new Long(longString2).longValue();

java.util.Date d1 = new java.util.Date(longType1);
java.util.Date d2 = new java.util.Date(longType2);

ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(longType1));
ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(longType2));
```

The problem is that in Oracle it is saved without the time part and only the date-

```
Date1                      Date2
--------------------------------------
15-MAR-18 00:00:00       20-MAR-18 00:00:00
```

Is there a way we can also preserve the time in Oracle. If I use the following I can see that the time part is preserved. But then that is current timestamp and I wanted the date/time corresponding to the time represented by the long milliseconds since epoch.

```
String query =  "insert into tempp values(sysdate , sysdate)";
```

Comment: use `java.sql.timestamp`, not `java.sql.date` in `ps.setDate`  `java.sql.date` per the documentation truncates the time portion.

Comment: @Joe you mean `ps.setTimestamp()`.

Comment: Actually both. `new java.sql.Date(longType1)` is wrong as well as `setDate`- use both `setTimestamp` after changing to `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: Table SQL definition would be helpful to understand Java to SQL type mapping.

Comment: @Joe No I meant your comment says to use `Timestamp` in `setDate`. I was correcting you on that part.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Kayaman for your suggsetions, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking you want a date in oracle, not a timestamp?
I am more of an oracle person than a java person but here it is, like the other commentators said it is java.sql.Timestamp that will get you the time part

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost/xe","scott","tiger");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        String query =  "insert into tempp values(? , ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String longString1 = "1521142078000";
        String longString2 = "1521566664738";

        long longType1 = Long.parseLong(longString1);
        long longType2 = Long.parseLong(longString2);

        Timestamp d1 = new Timestamp(longType1);
        Timestamp d2 = new Timestamp(longType2);

        ps.setTimestamp(1, d1);
        ps.setTimestamp(2, d2);

        ps.execute();
    }

}
```

here is the table

```
create table tempp (a date, b date);
```

here is the result

```
select to_char(a,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_char(b,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from tempp;
```

03/15/2018 15:27:58 03/20/2018 13:24:24